# If the coordinate functions of $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are periodic, is $f$ periodic too?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Is it true that if the coordinate functions of $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are periodic, then $f$ is periodic?

I think that he answer is yes, since I've done some problems where every time the coordinate functions where periodic, the function was periodic. Am I right? How do I show this or write this correctly? Thanks

Comment: $f(x) = (frac(\frac{1}{\pi}x), frac(\frac{1}{e}x))$, where $frac(y)$ is the fractional part of $y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Suppose that the component functions $f_1, f_2$ of $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ have respective minimal periods $T_1, T_2 > 0$. If $f$ is periodic, say, if $f(x + S) = f(x)$ for some $S > 0$, then $f_1(x + S) = f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x + S) = f_2(x)$. By minimality $S$ is an integer multiple of both $T_1$ and $T_2$ and thus $T_2 / T_1$ is rational.

Contrapositively, if we take functions $f_1, f_2$ with minimal periods $T_1, T_2$ for which $T_2 / T_1$ is irrational, the function $f = (f_1, f_2)$ will not be periodic. Of course, we can construct such a pair by taking a periodic function $f_1$ with minimal period $T_1 > 0$ and declare $f_2(x) := f_1(a x)$ for any irrational $a$.

Comment: I didn't understand Why the fact that $S$ is a multiple of both $T_1$ and $T_2$, $\frac{T_2}{T_1}$.

Comment: Since $f_1(x + S) = f_1(x)$, $S$ is a period of $f_1$. Since $f_1$ has a minimal period $T_1$, $S$ must be an integer multiple of $T_1$. (Suppose not, and write $S = \lambda T_1$; by hypothesis, $\lambda$ is a noninteger larger than $1$. Now, $0 < (\lambda - \lfloor\lambda\rfloor) T_1 < T_1$, but $(\lambda - \lfloor\lambda\rfloor) T_1 = S - \lfloor\lambda\rfloor T_1$, which is an integer combination of periods and thus is a (positive) period of $f_1$ smaller than $T_1$, which contradicts minimality.) The same applies to $f_2$, of course.

Comment: I see. It is necessary to apply minimality?

Comment: Yes. If $f_1, f_2$ are both constant then all positive numbers are periods of both $f_1, f_2$, so the argument fails. For a more sophisticated example, take $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: NB in the case where we have minimal periods the converse holds, too, that is, if the ratio $T_2 / T_1$ of the minimal periods of $f_1, f_2$ is rational then $f = (f_1, f_2)$ will be periodic.

Comment: What does minimal periods means exactly, I'm not sure I getting it right.

Comment: A positive number $S$ is a _period_ of a function $g : \Bbb R \to X$ iff $g(x + S) = g(x)$. If there's a smallest period $T$, we call that period _minimal_, in which case an argument similar to the one above shows that the periods of $g$ are exactly $T, 2 T, 3 T, \ldots$. As we've seen, not all periodic functions have minimal periods (and this is basically the reason for the necessity of using the condition "minimal" throughout my answer): A not-quite-trivial example to keep in mind is that every positive rational number is a period of the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. The key is in the fact that for $f$ to be periodic $\frac{T_2}{T_1}$ must be rational, right? Is a counterexample a prove?

Comment: Yes, a single counterexample is enough to show that the statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=(\sin \,x , \sin (\sqrt 2 x)$ is easily seen to be a counterexample.

Comment: It is a counterexample because $\sqrt(2)$ is irrational, right? Can I just use a counterexample to prove it?

Comment: @davidllerenav It is enough to give one counterexample to show that $f$ need not be  periodic. Yes, $\sqrt 2$ is irrational and that is why my example works.